# A weaker conjecture than a known conjecture

Tags: soft-question, conjectures

I really apologize if my question is not appropriate here, though I hope it is.

Let $C$ be any known conjecture in mathematics, which is still open.
Let $D$ be another conjecture such that a positive answer to conjecture $C$ implies a positive answer to conjecture $D$.
Now assume that one proved conjecture $D$.

> Do you think that mathematicians working on conjecture $C$ will find such a result interesting?

Of course, if one has found a counterexample to conjecture $D$, then conjecture $C$ is false, but this is not the situation I am asking about.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Of course they would.  If nothing else, it's likely, or at least possible,  that the techniques used to prove $D$ will shed some light on the broader conjecture.

Comment: Thank you @lulu for your comment.

Comment: Let C be the Reimann hypothesis and D be 1+1=2.  Recall that $$D \implies (C \implies D)$$

Comment: @Michael, do you say that knowing that $C \longrightarrow D$ may be useless? (I guess so). Probably the more light the proof of $D$ sheds on conjecture $C$, the more important it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is discussed at some length in George Pólya's book *Mathematics and Plausible Reasoning* Vol. 2, [*Patterns of Plausible Inference*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematics_and_Plausible_Reasoning#Volume_II:_Patterns_of_Plausible_Inference). He points out, for instance, that if $A$ implies $B$, and if $B$ is quite plausible in itself, then verifying $B$ makes $A$ just a little bit more credible; but if $B$ was very improbable in itself, then verifying $B$ makes $A$ much more credible.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! Nice.